# My custom beat cant find custombeat.yml when I try to run it from a container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

So, I have built a beat with mage GenerateCustomBeat and it runs okay, except, now I'm trying to cotainerize it. When I run the image I built, it complains that no customBeat.yml was found.
I have secured that the file exists in the folder by adding a line `RUN ls .` at the end of my Dockerfile.

The beat name is coletorbeat, so this name appears multiple times inside the Dockerfile.

Upon executing `sudo docker run coletorbeat` I have the following error message:
`Exiting: error loading config file: stat coletorbeat.yml: no such file or directory` 
If there was a way to specify the coletorbeat.yml file location when I execute the beat, in `CMD` I think I would solve it, but I have not found how to do so yet.

I'll post the Dockerfile below. I know the code inside the beater folder works fine. I'm guessing I'm making some mistake on the containerization.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER myNameHere

ARG ${ip:-"333.333.333.333"}
ARG ${porta:-"4343"}
ARG ${dataInicio:-"2020-01-07"}
ARG ${dataFim:-"2020-01-07"}
ARG ${tipoEquipamento:-"type"}
ARG ${versao:-"2"}
ARG ${nivel:-"0"}
ARG ${instituicao:-"RJ"}

ADD . .
RUN mkdir /etc/coletorbeat
COPY /coletorbeat/coletorbeat.yml /etc/coletorbeat/coletorbeat.yml

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget git
RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxvf go1.14.*.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local
RUN mkdir /go

ENV GOROOT /usr/local/go
ENV GOPATH $HOME/go
ENV PATH $PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

RUN echo $PATH
RUN go get -u -d github.com/magefile/mage
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/magefile/mage && \
    go run bootstrap.go
RUN apt-get install -y python3-venv
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN cd /coletorbeat && chmod go-w coletorbeat.yml && ./coletorbeat setup
RUN cd /coletorbeat && ./coletorbeat test config -c /coletorbeat/coletorbeat.yml && ls .

CMD ./coletorbeat/coletorbeat -E 'coletorbeat.ip=${ip}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the yml file into the /etc dir

```
COPY /coletorbeat/coletorbeat.yml /etc/coletorbeat/coletorbeat.yml
```

But then running commands on `/coletorbeat` without using etc.

Comment: Ahh that addition was an attempt to see if the beat would recognize the file in that directory, as a default from Libbeat. BUT I can confirm the file is within /coletorbeat folder, the same folder I run the beat from. I have added a line to list the folder's files with the `ls` command, it IS there. I copied the beat's folder entirely from the Dockerfile's location to the root folder of the container with `. .` that part was indeed unclear.

Comment: What if you set the WORKDIR in the directory before executing the command? Something like:

WORKDIR /coletorbeat/
CMD ./coletorbeat -E 'coletorbeat.ip=${ip}'

Answer (score 0):

On `CMD` line in the `Dockerfile`, I added the command cd /mybeatfolder and it worked. Libbeat searches the current folder  for the config file as default, so moving to the right directory before executing my beat solved it.